# "Add Token" in Metamask

Tags: tokens, metamask

Why is it necessary to manually add a token you will transact in (before the actual transaction) in Metamask? What happens if someone doesn't do that before a transaction, to display that balance in Metamask?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metamask doesn't collect information about a token unless you add the token. Internally metamask starts listening to events of the particular smart contract to provide you the balance of your addresses in those contracts.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. But what happens if someone doesn't add the token first? Can't Metamask query the contract to get my balance, if someone adds it later?

Comment: Yes, you can add it at any moment, then metamask will show your token balance.